# why my Azure data factory pipeline failed because of my local ip is not whitelisted?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Let's say, I vpn into my corpnet, my ip in the corpnet is 12.34.56.78
then I rdp to a server, its ip is 123.123.123.123
then I open Azure data factory in an web explorer from the rdp server, create a trigger to run my pipeline on schedule
but the triggered pipeline run failed with error message like "12.34.56.78 is not allowed to access the destination Azure sql database".

I know that I didn't add 12.34.56.78 into my Azure SQL server whitelist, but why is it even matter? the pipeline is kicked off by a trigger, and that trigger shouldn't have anything to do with my laptop ip.
Besides, the pipeline failed after 3 and half hour running, and it didn't fail when I test run it with a much smaller test set earlier, it doesn't seem like it can not connect to the Azure db in the first try.

Can someone please help me understand which ip is the one Azure pipeline use to access the database?

Comment: that's odd, Azure pipelines do use auto hosted integration runtime (non-ssis and on prem connections) and hence you do not have any control over the ip address with which they access your SQL Azure instance. Just to ensure - have you enabled the 'Allow access to Azure Services' settings on your sql azure?  Also, what sort of pipeline activities you have used in your adf pipeline? any proxy or anything that routes the connection to sq azure with some on-prem connectivity?

Comment: Are you talking about the Azure DevOps scheduled pipeline? Please refer to [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops) and check if that helps.

Comment: huge "thank you" to Bhushan and Andy, I figured out the problem and it is silly: the self-hosted integrationRuntime was on that ip...